# Change docker root path in centos

Tags: docker, centos, docker-compose, centos7, docker-swarm

I am having docker version installed:

`Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40`.

`OS: centos 7`

I want to change default docker root to `/var/some_path`.

I found **three ways**:

1. In file `/etc/sysconfig/docker` add **(Not working)**

   `OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled --log-driver=journald --signature-verification=false -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -g /var/vms/docker'[centos@ip-172-31-1-225`

when I reload and restart docker, nothing happens. It take root directory as `/var/lib/docker`.

2. In `/etc/docker/daemon.json` add (**Not working**)

   {
       "graph": "/var/vms/docker",
       "storage-driver": "overlay"
   }

**It complains that:**

```
unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives are specified both as a flag and in the configuration file:
```

graph: (from flag: /var/lib/docker, from file: /var/vms/docker), storage-driver: (from flag: overlay, from file: overlay)

So I removed `--graph=/opt/afp/docker --storage-driver=overlay` form `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/execstart.conf`.

**After this** when I reload and restart docker

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

**I get error** :

```
Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: overlay: the backing xfs filesystem is formatted without d_type support, which leads to incorrect behavior. Reformat the filesystem with ftype=1 to enable d_type support. Backing filesystems without d_type support are not supported.
```

3. In `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/execstart.conf` add (**Not working**):

   `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --graph=/var/lib/vms/docker --storage-driver=overlay`

(also remove `/etc/docker/daemon.json` added in step 2)

**I get same error**:

`Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: overlay: the backing xfs filesystem is formatted without d_type support, which leads to incorrect behavior. Reformat the filesystem with ftype=1 to enable d_type support. Backing filesystems without d_type support are not supported.`

Note (**important**):  When the root path `--graph=/var/lib/docker` , everything works fine.

Comment: `overlay2` also showing the same error. Also when `--graph=/var/lib/docker` everything works fine.

Comment: As shown [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#prerequisites), centos and its filesystem requires a bit more workaround in order to make the overlay (or overlay2) driver work. However, I don't know why you need to change the driver in order to changer your `docker` path

Comment: [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-do-i-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory/1169) could help you for your issue

Comment: @Aserre actually this was the 1st among 3 ways I found to solve the problem. (didn't solve)

Comment: You don't use the `other_args` parameter in the code sample you've shown

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the new mount path is of xfs( with ftype=1 ) or ext4 partition.
   for checking xfd:  xfs_info  
   Its because docker files work only on either of the two partitions.
   If your new mount type is above mentioned, then follow step 2.
2. Stop the docker
   sudo systemctl stop docker
3. Create a file in location /etc/docker with name daemon.json.

```
nano /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

give the below infos in the file:

```
{
    "data-root": "/mnt/customlocation/docker-data",
    "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

4. Start the docker

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
```

5. Verification. Type command:

```
docker info
```

check for the docker root directory

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change docker root directory by creating a systemd drop-in service file. This is useful when you want images and containers or docker generated files to be located in another partition or drive.

A unit configuration file whose name ends in .service encodes information about a process controlled and supervised by systemd. Docker has one of those.

You should avoid modifying a `.service` file directly as it could be overwritten during an update. This is why it is preferred to create a systemd drop-in service file. Drop-in service file only changes the specific settings one is interested in. Note that multiple drop-in files are read if present.

More information on this article :
https://medium.com/@wlarch/change-docker-root-directory-by-creating-a-systemd-drop-in-service-file-3c1244244784